# Writing Dataset to MS SQL server fails

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

- java 8
- mssql-jdbc: 7.4.0.jre8
- spark-core_2.12: 2.4.4
- spark-sql_2.12: 2.4.4

I am trying to fetch a spark dataset, sourced from an MS SQL 2007 Server table and write it to another existing table(fails with new tablename also) on the same database after a few transformations. The contents of the dataset seem fine on executing a .show().  No matter if I try to write using SaveMode.Append or SaveMode.Overwrite, spark tries to create a new table and fails with the error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ';'. On debugging, the jdbc driver breaks on the following statement:

`CREATE TABLE "RMS.cacr_rms.POC_REFUND_DETAILS"; ("REFUND_ID" NVARCHAR(MAX) , "ORDER_ID" NVARCHAR(MAX) , "PROFILE_ID" NVARCHAR(MAX) , "AGENT_ID" INTEGER , "CONSUMER_ID" INTEGER , "REASON_CODE_ID" INTEGER , "REFUND_TYPE" INTEGER , "STORE_ID" INTEGER , "STATUS" NVARCHAR(MAX) , "REFUND_CREATED_DATE" DATETIME , "LAST_UPDATED_DATE" INTEGER , "ORDER_SUBMITTED_DATE" DATETIME , "SHIP_DATE" INTEGER , "ORDER_AMOUNT" INTEGER , "REFUND_AMOUNT" INTEGER , "REFUND_CHANNEL" INTEGER , "TENANT" INTEGER , "VERTICAL" INTEGER , "ATG_REFUND_ID" NVARCHAR(MAX) )`

Additional info: The JdbcRelationProvider class in spark sql has the attribute tableExists false.

Full stacktrace:

```
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ';'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1624)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:868)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:768)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2979)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:248)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:223)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerStatement.java:711)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.createTable(JdbcUtils.scala:859)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at RmsSparkSession.write(RmsSparkSession.java:27)
    at MainApp.main(MainApp.java:28)
```

Code which triggered error:

````
ds.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).format("jdbc").option("url", config.getString("sqlserver.url"))
        .option("dbtable", tableName).option("user", config.getString("sqlserver.username"))
        .option("password", config.getString("sqlserver.password")).save();```
````

Comment: are you sure you need that semicolon? Isn't create table not a complete statement until you define its fields? I am guessing here -- trying to help

Comment: Jeremy is correct - that semicolon is a mistake. But I see all sorts of other problems with the attempted table schema and will guess that the code which leads to this error has other problems. Highly doubtful that most (perhaps all) of your nvarchar(max) columns should actually be strings. Nor should they be GIANT strings. Last_Updated_Date (and others) should not be integer. Your table name will confuse anyone trying to use it as you used a 3-part string as the table name. Monetary amounts are not generally whole numbers.

Comment: @Smor The schema is implicitly defined by spark when reading the data. I can explicitly define a schema myself, but the issue here seems to be spark failing to find the table and failing to create a new table also, because of this syntax error in generated sql

Answer (score 0):

SaveMode.Overwrite would create the table and SaveMode.Append would append to the existing table without creating it.

Please try this syntax, it works for me.

```
    Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
    connectionProps.put("user", config.getString("sqlserver.username"));
    connectionProps.put("password", config.getString("sqlserver.password");
    connectionProps.put("driver", connection details);

    dataframe.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(jdbcURL, tableName, connectionProps)
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html for setting JDBC properties.

Comment: It still fails for me. Spark tries to create a table with erroneous SQL even with savemode append. What did work was using azure-sqldb-spark connector and doing a bulk copy, since I want to prioritize speed anyways.

Comment: I am not  sure why, the above code works on Oracle in both append and overwrite mode. Have you tried charging spark version if there’s is a bug. I have used 2.4.2

Comment: Unfortunately I could not get it to work with MS SQL server. However, using [azure-sqldb-spark](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark) connector works for standard jdbc writes and bulk insert writes. The connector internally uses the same jdbc driver. Bulk insert mode also seems to provide a significant performance improvement when dealing with large data.